# Vue this.$refs returns an object that looks empty but has the value in the inspector

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a watch method to watch a prop for changes, when that happens I would like to autofocus an input element, I'm using the following code

```
  watch: {
    currentBookEntry: {
      immediate: true,
      handler: function() {
        console.log(this.$refs)
        console.log(this.$refs.inputElement)
      }
    }
  },
```

**this.$refs.inputElement returns undefined, and this.$refs returns a sort of empty object**, in the screenshot you see it doesn't have the inputElement data, but if I click it open in the inspector I do see the data there, what kind of sourcery is this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#vm-nextTick
Wait until after the next DOM update cycle.

```
this.$nextTick(function(){
  console.log(this.$refs.inputElement)
})
```